# Transform config in asp.net mvc isnt updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I have asp.net mvc 4 project where try to use transform config, where have some default values and when I try to change to release mode some default values change to release values, but it isnt work. When I try to change to release mode and build application I have nothing changes. Here is my default values in Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="appId" value="####"/>
    <add key="appSecret" value="####"/>
    <add key="hostName" value="####"/>
  </appSettings>
```

And here is what I have in my Web.Release.config:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <appSettings>
    <add key="appId" value="!!!!" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    <add key="appSecret" value="!!!!" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add key="hostName" value="!!!!" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Does anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"`, you're trying to match an attribute `name` which does not exist. You're looking for `key` for the appSettings:

```
<add key="appId" value="!!!!" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
<add key="appSecret" value="!!!!" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
<add key="hostName" value="!!!!" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

Comment: Try to change name to key and the same situation.

Comment: @BorHunter Make sure you have selected the correct configuration (Release). Also, this is not generated on *build* rather on *deploy*

Comment: Yes I'm select release. May you explain your phrase: " this is not generated on build rather on deploy "

Comment: The resulting Web.config is only generated on right-click `Project > Publish`. It is not generated when simply using `Build Solution`.

Comment: Interesting, but what I should to do if I Publish my project by copy/paste files on server instead of Publish? May you help me?

Comment: @BorHunter That is creating a lot of hassle for yourself really. Use the Publish dialog, create a new profile, then select `"File System"` as the connection. Maybe even FTP if you have the details. You'll be surprised at how much time you can save yourself by doing it this way :)